# iOS 7 Status Bar weird behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uistatusbar, ios7-statusbar

I'm using a UISplitViewController for an iPad app and I get a weird behavior from the StatusBar.

Here's how I initialize my RootViewController:

```
if(kIosVersionFloat >= 7.0)
        [application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
    [application setStatusBarHidden:NO];
_window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

        _rootNavigationVC = [[YTRootNavigationController alloc] init];
        _rootNavigationVC.navigationBarHidden = YES;

        NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
        shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8];
        shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                               [UIColor colorWithRed:245.0/255.0 green:245.0/255.0 blue:245.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                               shadow, NSShadowAttributeName,
                                                               [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack" size:21.0], NSFontAttributeName, nil]];

        // RootViewController* firstVC = [[RootViewController alloc] init];

        detailViewController= [[iPadDetailViewController alloc]init];
        YTRootNavigationController *navC = [[YTRootNavigationController alloc]init];
        [navC pushViewController:detailViewController animated:NO];
        navC.navigationBarHidden = YES;
        _slidingVC = [[YTBaseViewController alloc] initWithViewClass:[YTSlidingContainerView class]];

        [_rootNavigationVC pushViewController:_slidingVC animated:NO];



        UISplitViewController* splitVC = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
        splitVC.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:_rootNavigationVC, navC, nil];

        _window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        _window.rootViewController = splitVC;

}
```

And this is how my app looks like:
[image: iPad Status Bar overlapping]

I have read a couple other posts on StackOverflow regarding the same issue but didn't get much result.

Any suggestions?

I am not using Storyboards or XIBs

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to the Navigation Bar from a property in your `iPadDetailViewController`, you can do the following:

First, in your `iPadDetailViewController.h`, implement the `UINavigationBarDelegate`

```
@interface iPadDetailViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationBarDelegate>
```

Then, in `iPadDetailViewController.m`, set `self.navigationBar.delegate = self` inside `viewDidLoad` and add the following method:

```
- (UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id<UIBarPositioning>)bar {
    CGRect frame = self.navigationBar.frame;
    frame.origin = CGPointMake(0, [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height);
    self.navigationBar.frame = frame;

    return UIBarPositionTopAttached;
}
```